# How to return a secure url?

Tags: magento-1.9, secure, geturl

I have got an issue with the search-bar on my magento website which keeps returning an unsecure url. Be aware I am a bit of a noob when it comes to php.
The url gets called in this form tag:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
```

How do I get this o call the secure url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved when i run my website with secure url.

From the research i got this solution for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched for the issue and found this solution, see if it works for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537864/catalog-search-magento-not-working-https-ssl

Comment: I did not understand the solution as it didn't really answer anything.